# Why is my React UseEffect (that uses Firebase onSnapshot) in an infinite loop, constantly mounting and unmounting?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I have a header (like facebook I suppose) and there is a notifications bell. I want to listen for new notifications on Firbase Firestore.

I've set up a `useEffect`, but theres an infinite loop for some reason, and I'm not sure why?

**Here is the `useEffect`/`useState`:**

```js
const [subbedToNotifications, setSubbedToNotifications] = useState(false);
//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
useEffect(() => {
    var unsubscribe = () => {
      console.log("this function does nothing");
    };
    console.log("subscribing to notifications");
    if (
      userData !== null &&
        auth.currentUser.uid !== null &&
        !subbedToNotifications
    ) {
      setSubbedToNotifications(true);
      unsubscribe = db
          .collection("users")
          .doc(auth.currentUser.uid)
          .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
          dispatch({
            type: "SET_USERDATA",
            userData: snapshot.data(),
          });
        });
    }
    // Detach listener
    return () => {
      console.log("unsubbing from notifications");
      unsubscribe();
      setSubbedToNotifications(false);
    };
  }, [subbedToNotifications]);
```

So, when the component mounts and whenever `subbedToNotifications` changes, it'll run this use effect. The IF wrapped around the call to Firebase requires `userData` (where I store things such as username, profile picture, bio etc.), firebase auth to not be empty, as well as `subbedToNotifications` to be false. When the call to firebase is made, `subbedToNotifications` is set to true, so Therefore that shouldn't be called again and should only be subscribed once.

Also the return unsubscribes from firebase, however the console logs were repeating:
`console.log("subscribing to notifications")` and `console.log("unsubbing from notifications")` constantly, racking up 6k reads to the database.

Can anyone spot my mistake as to why the `useEffect` is getting into a loop, or perhaps why the Header is constantly mounting and unmounting?

TIA!

Comment: Are you sure `setSubbedToNotifications` isn't called anywhere outside infinitely?

Comment: @UdenduAbasili Nope, just in initialization (https://gyazo.com/15c80c8db94bb7c2fd3105ee53e89006)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `[subbedToNotifications]` to `[]`

Comment: Ok will give it a try now!

Comment: Yepp that fixed it. Very strange, I used a similar useEffect in another component, but with an input instead of an empty [] and that worked fine. Thank you!