Endless loop data request on firebase database (React)
i have this code here
import { RiDeleteBin6Line } from "react-icons/ri";
import { FaExchangeAlt } from "react-icons/fa";
import { ref, child, get } from 'firebase/database';
import { getDatabase } from 'firebase/database';
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export const CardDateList = ( ) => {
    

  const [locationData, setLocationData] = useState(null);
  const [locationUser, setLocationUser] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
      const dbRef = ref(getDatabase());
      const auth = getAuth();
      const user = auth.currentUser?.reloadUserInfo?.localId;
  
      if (user) {
        get(child(dbRef, `locations/identify/${user}`))
          .then((snapshot) => {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
              setLocationUser(snapshot.val().name);

              get(child(dbRef, 'locations/public/' + (locationUser) + '/availabledates/')).then(
                (snapshot) => {
                  if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    setLocationData(snapshot.val());
                    console.log(locationData);
                  } else {
                    console.log("No data available");
                  }
                  setLoading(false);
                },
              );
            } else {
              console.log("No data available");
              setLoading(false);
            }
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
            setLoading(false);
          });
      } else {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    }, [locationUser, locationData]);
    
   if (loading) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }
  
    if (!locationData) {
      return <div>No data available</div>;
    }
          
  return (
    <div className='container_date_element'>
        <label>
            <div className='container_date_list_element'>
                <form className='form_date_list_element'>
                    <div className='list_element'>
                        <label>Datum</label>
                        <br></br>
                        <input value={locationData.capacity}/>
                    </div>
                    <div className='list_element'>
                        <label>Genre</label>
                        <br></br>
                        <input></input>
                    </div>
                    <div className='list_element'>
                        <label>Kategorie</label>
                        <br></br>
                        <input></input>
                    </div>
                    <div className='list_element'>
                        <label>Gage</label>
                        <br></br>
                        <input></input>
                    </div>
                    <div className='list_date_button'>
                          <button><FaExchangeAlt/></button>
                          <button><RiDeleteBin6Line/></button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </label>
    </div>
  );
}; 


The problem is that the code continuously retrieves the locationUser data from firebase database (i can see this in my console in the chrome browser). The aim would be for it to retrieve this only once.
Can anyone tell me what the reason is for this endless loop? Is this a called re-rendering?
I'm not really familiar with React yet and would be grateful for a brief explanation.

It looks like you have specified no dependencies for your useEffect hook, which means that it is executed on every render of the UI. And since it changes the state, it causes a rerender of the UI itself. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70309336/use-effect-and-firebase-causing-infinite-loop for an example of a dependency (that's for Firestore, but the same approach works for any asynchronous data source) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67405699/why-is-my-react-useeffect-that-uses-firebase-onsnapshot-in-an-infinite-loop-c and https://stackoverflow.com/a/58710950

@MHDAlaaAlhaj if i change it to [] the console shows me "No Data available"

Thats likely because of a bug I see in your implementation. You do setLocationUser(snapshot.val().name) then immediately after you reference locationUser. The value of locationUser will not be the the value you just set. Since state setting actions in react are queued. See https://react.dev/learn/state-as-a-snapshot. This would mean that likely, it only got the data before because the effect was running too many times, so the second time it ran, it would have the value of locationUser set on the previous. So that part was accidentally working.

To fix it, do something like const newLocationUser = snapshot.val().name; following by setLocationUser(newLocationUser ); and then get(child(dbRef, 'locations/public/' + (newLocationUser) + '/availabledates/')).then(

Finally, remove locationUser and locationData from the use effect deps. It should be only [] after the above changes, since the effect will not actually directly reference the locationUser state item (setter doesn't count). And it never did reference locationData.

Actually just noticed it did reference locationData for sake of logging. But this log line makes no sense as its logging after state has been set in the same effect -- it would log old value anyway and not do what you think it does. The state set is not immediate, its async in that its applied on next render. Move any logging of this outside the effect entirely. Now you should be left with an empty deps array [] and everything should work.

See https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#ive-updated-the-state-but-logging-gives-me-the-old-value, which I think concisely describes where your mental model is going wrong.

@adsy thank you. I will try to change the code as you described
